# Cambiar el color de un Item del menú dinámicamente

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy intentando que de alguna manera cuando estes en la pagina "dashboard" por ejemplo, en el menu este resaltado de un color, y al cambiar a otra página, esta otra se resalte de un color. Programando en MVC lo veo complicado, no encuentro la forma.

```
    <li class="nav-item start active open">
    <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>dashboard.php" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="icon-home"></i>
        <span class="title">Dashboard</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="heading">
    <h3 class="uppercase">Library</h3>
</li>
<li class="nav-item  ">
    <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>books" class="nav-link ">
        <i class="icon-book-open"></i>
        <span class="title">Books</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Actualmente el dashboard.php tiene la etiqueta en el li de "active open" y el span de "selected". Como podría cambiar eso según la página en la que este?

Comment: En cada vista armas el menu o tienes un layout para el menu y cada vista se alimenta de ese layout?

Comment: Tengo el menu en un layout aparte (un archivo en html/navs) y en las vistas imprimo el layout con ob_start();
        include "../html/nav/nav.php";
        $nav = ob_get_clean();
        echo $nav;

Comment: una ultika consulta estas utilizando algun framework o es mvc puro?

Comment: @sioesi ¿quisiste decir PHP puro?

Comment: si xD, perdon! @Shaz

Comment: es php puro, no uso ningun framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar esta funcion, que devuelve en base a tu URL la accion en la que esta.

```
function verificarURL($action){
    $current_action = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");
    $current_action = strtok($current_action, '?');
    if ($current_action == $action){
        echo 'class="nav-item start active open"';
    } else {
        echo 'class="nav-item"';
    }
}
```

Por otro lado, la lista en tu `nav.php`

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="dashboard.php" <?=verificarURL("dashboard")?>>DashBoard</a></li>
    <li><a href="books.php" <?=verificarURL("books")?>>Books</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Llama a la funcion`verificarURL` y envia por parametro la accion que espera para estar activo. Si la accionen la que esta, es igual a la que envia por parametro, se le imprime la clase `start active open`, de lo contrario solo `nav-item`

**EDICION**

Respecto a los problemas que te surgieron, para quitar los parametros en caso de que vengan por get

```
$current_action = strtok($current_action, '?');
```

Comment: Esta funcion funciona perfectamente! Muchas gracias :D

Comment: si te sirvio mi respuesta recuerda marcarla :D, saludos! @CharlieClewer

Comment: Respecto a esta función, me ha surgido un problema. Si hay datos en el get, por ejemplo un codigo de error o una id, no me lo valida la url y me imprime el active open. ¿Habría alguna posibilidad de editarla para que ignorase si hay datos en el get?

Comment: Además, añado que existe el problema de los <li> dropdowns, cuando estan en la pagina del dropdown, me gustaría que se cambiase la clase solo del padre, es decir el <li> que engloba el dropdown.

Comment: @CharlieClewer ya solucione uno de tus problemas, podrias editar tu pregunta y agregar los `<li>` dropdowns para ver como los trabajas y ayudarte?

Comment: Lo de los dropdowns ya lo solucione, no lo pensé bien. Sobre lo del GET, donde iría esa linea de código?

Comment: dentro de la funcion `verificarURL`, despues de inicializar la variabe `$current_action`

Comment: lo he intentado pero no funciona, en al respuesta de abajo tengo la funcion entera

Comment: @CharlieClewer ya edite la funcion, no tienes que volver a editarla. Y segundo donde estan tus links con parametros GET?

Comment: Sí, son parametros GET. Esta la url normal, sin el get (si marca la barra del menu) http://localhost:8080/CBSLibrary/search.php -- Y esta es la que tiene el GET, que no marca el menu. http://localhost:8080/CBSLibrary/search.php?error=004

Comment: Aun no he podido encontrar el problema del porque no funciona si la url tiene un parametro get.

Answer (score 0):

Sobre las dos preguntas que hice anteriormente respecto al mismo tema:

1. ¿Donde exactamente añado la linea de código que has puesto en la edición?

> ```
> function verificarURL($action) {
>   $current_action = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");
>   $current_action = strtok($current_action, '?');
>   if ($current_action == $action){
>       echo 'active open';
>   }
> }
> ```

Si es así, no me ha funcionado.

```
<li class="nav-item <?=verificarURL("search")?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>search.php" class="nav-link ">
        <i class="icon-magnifier"></i>
        <span class="title">Advanced Search</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Tengo ese li donde a veces además de search.php va un get con el error en plan "search.php?error=001"

**EDITADO** La pregunta sobre el dropdown ya lo he arreglado, gracias de todas formas :)

Para los que no sepan, solo he puesto en el primer item del dropdown esto:

```
<li class="nav-item <?= verificarURL("settings"); verificarURL("library"); ?>">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-toggle">
        <i class="icon-settings"></i>
        <span class="title">Settings</span>
        <span class="selected"></span>
        <span class="arrow open"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="nav-item <?=verificarURL("settings");?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>administration/settings/settings.php" class="nav-link ">
                <span class="title">Main Settings</span>
                <span class="selected"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item start <?=verificarURL("library");?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>administration/settings/library.php" class="nav-link ">
                <span class="title">Library Settings</span>
                <span class="selected"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: igual ocupaste mi funcion :D

Comment: @sioesi No sé porque la funcion sigue si cambiar el color del menu cuanto tiene datos en el get.

Comment: puedes imprimir que te devuelve la funcion `verificarURL` cuando tiene parametros get?

Comment: @sioesi No imprime nada si tiene un get

Comment: Puedes dentro de la funcion imprimir `$action` y `$current_action`?

Comment: authors
authors.php eso me imprime el action y el current action @sioesi

Comment: @sioesi aún sigo sin encontrar el error por el cual no me añade las etiquetas css cuando la url tiene un parametro get